# Javascript var === 2 && console.log('true'). How does this work?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

```
var test = 2;

test === 2 && console.log('true');
```

This confuses me. I hadn't seen this before until the other day. The output of this will be `true` in the console.

So how does this magic work?

Comment: It's not a magic, just bad style. `cond && do_something` is the same as `if(cond) do_something`.

Comment: @georg How is this syntactically valid? What is the variable being created?

Comment: What exactly confuses you about it?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works, as it is not something I have ever seen done before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This (mis)uses the boolean handling of JavaScript; because of the lazy evaluation of expressions,
`console.log('true')` is only run, when `someVar === 2` was previously evaluated as `true`.

This behaviour is called [*Short-circuit evaluation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

#### Other use-cases

By the way, this type of coding has legit use cases. My favourite is the use of *configuration objects*:

```
function (options) {
    var options = options || {};
}
```

This way, the options object exists even if it was not given in as a parameter.

Comment: This would be true if there were a variable name after `var`, as it is, you get a syntax error

Comment: The `var` was just a placeholder used by OP, he fixed his error.

Comment: There were a number of edits to the post.  At one point it was indeed edited to say "someVar === 2" but then your edit took that out.

Comment: Thank you for this, and actually understanding what I meant initially. Haha. Now that you mention it, I have used that function example before, but a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this code isn't valid:

```
var === 2 && console.log('true')
   VM132:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ===
```

You can try it yourself in the browser (i.e. in Chrome look for Developer Tools).

See http://jsfiddle.net/jcdxnte0/

---

**EDIT:**

The syntax `x && y` means that both `x` and `y` need to be true. This means, that if `x` is true, `y` will get evaluated, and if `x` is false, `y` will not get evaluated (because `x` was false, so **both** will never be true so why bother evaluating `y`? - evaluation goes from left to right). In your case, `x` is `test === 2`, and `y` is `console.log(...)`.

Comment: i think its just a typo

Comment: I think he meant, something like this: `var a = 2; a === 2 && console.log('true')`. By `var` he meant that you should replace it with a variable name.

Comment: Yeah I was using the generic var in place of a name. Updated for less confusion.

Answer (score 2):

it can be read as

```
if( test === 2 ){ console.log('true'); }
```

It works because `(test === 2)` is an *expression* which *resolves to a value*.
It'll resolve to either true or false. JavaScript will then execute code after `&&` only if the preceding expression returned true. (so `false && console.log()` won't log anything).

Another fun way to abuse it and confuse other developers is the fact that assignment also returns a value, for example

```
var x = 0, y = 5;
(x = y) && console.log( 'x is now 5' );
```

in this case `(x = y)` not only assigns the value of `y` to `x`, but also returns `5` which is truthy, so the `console.log` gets evaluated. *don't use this, please*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and that second part. That's amusing. I wouldn't ever use it, I just saw it in an article. I tend to not use things that can confuse as I am not the only person that works with the JS on the project. It is however odd that I haven't ever seen this since I started JS development...

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript evaluates the left part and, if it's true, executes the right part. You can do the opposite with the `||` operator.

It's also worth noting that the right part should be wrapped in parenthesis if it contains an assignment:

```
var foo;   
true && (foo = "bar");
```

While it's perfectly valid, I'd recommend not using this syntax.

Comment: Syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var` http://jsfiddle.net/d5pm5sve/

Comment: That was just an example demonstrating the principle. Edited the code for correctness.